# x64 vs x86 Performance Considerations .Net

Tags: c#, performance, 64-bit

I am trying to understand what performance differences exist when running a native C# / .Net 4.0 app in x64 vs x86. I understand the memory considerations (x64 addressing all memory, x86 limited to 2/4gb), as well as the fact that an x64 app will use more memory (all pointers are 8 bytes instead of 4 bytes). As far as I can tell, none of these should affect any of the clock for clock instructions, as the x64 pipeline is wide enough to handle the wider instructions.

Is there a performance hit in context switching, due to the larger stack size for each thread? What performance considerations am I missing in evaluating the two?

Comment: Have you benchmarked both or is this a thought experiment? If you benchmarked, what were the results?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Joe White has given you some good reasons why your app might be slower. Larger pointers (and therefore by extension larger references in .NET) will take up more space in memory, meaning less of your code and data will fit into the cache.

There are, however, plenty of beneficial reasons you might want to use x64:

- The AMD64 calling convention is used by default in x64 and can be quite a bit faster than the standard cdecl or stdcall, with many arguments being passed in registers and using the XMM registers for floating point.
- The CLR will emit scalar SSE instructions for dealing with floating point operations in 64-bit. In x86 it falls back on using the standard x87 FP stack, which is quite a bit slower, especially for things like converting between ints and floats.
- Having more registers means that there is much less chance that the JIT will have to spill them due to register pressure. Spilling registers can be quite costly for fast inner loops, especially if a function gets inlined and introduces additional register pressure there.
- Any operations on 64-bit integers can benefit tremendously by being able to fit into a single register instead of being broken up into two separate halves.
- This may be obvious, but the additional memory your process can access can be quite useful if your application is memory-intensive, even if it isn't hitting the theoretical limit. Fragmentation can cause you to hit "out of memory" conditions long before you reach that mark.
- RIP-relative addressing in x64 can, in some cases, [reduce the size of an executable image](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=192). Although that doesn't really apply directly to .NET apps, it *can* have an effect on the sharing of DLLs which may otherwise have to be relocated. I'd be interested in knowing if anyone has any specific information on this with regards to .NET and managed applications.

Aside from these, the x64 version of the .NET runtime seems to, at least in the current versions, perform more optimizations than the x86 equivalent. Things like inlining and memory alignment seem to happen much more often. In fact, there was a bug a while back that prevented inlining of any method that took or returned a value type; I remember seeing it fixed in x64 and not the x86 version.

Really, the only way you'll be able to tell which is better for your app will be to do profiling and testing on both architectures and comparing real results. However, I personally just use Any CPU wherever possible and avoid anything inherently architecture-dependent. This makes it easy to build and deploy, and is hopefully more future proof when the majority of users start switching to x64 exclusively.

Comment: The number of registers do not change anything, in modern CPUs, since the asm code is translated into micro ops. x64 on general purpose code tends to be slower than x86, when working with integer and memory. SSE2 FPU is faster than x87, on the other hand. But as always, what will be *much faster* could be to change the algorithm used (e.g. use cache or lookup tables), not the CPU target.

Comment: Having more registers at your disposal most certainly does change things. Even with the register renaming that x86 processors perform, it can't do anything about explicit dependencies the compiler is forced to make by the limited register set. Additionally, "changing the algorithm" is not what this question was about, which is why nobody bothered to mention it.

Answer (score 4):

Closely related to "x64 app will use more memory" is the fact that, with a 64-bit app, your locality of reference is smaller (because all your pointer sizes are doubled), so you get less mileage out of the CPU's on-board (ultra-fast) cache. You have to retrieve data from system RAM more often, which is much slower than the L2 and even the L1 on-chip cache.